# Angular 2 Router: Not returning to base href after page reload

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have different route paths. The base `href` is set to "/", and the root path is linked to the app.component, which consists of the router outlet. While navigating through the site, the window URL changes to "path1", "path2", and so on.

Now the problem...

By refreshing the page, with "path1" for instance, the page reloads the content of the "path1" component, instead of initially linking to the root path.

I need a page reload linking to the root path.

Can you help me with figuring why this happens?

Comment: From a UX standpoint, you probably don't want to do this. Its reasonable for  a web user to expect to stay on the same page if they refresh. Redirecting them without warning or cause could make for a confusing experience.

Comment: It is a web application, and the user needs to start from the root path. Otherwise, major important classes are not being initialized and values will be undefined.

Comment: That sounds more like an architecture problem, not a user problem. Are you relying on any [guards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) with your routes? A resolver could load the required data before the component renders (thus solving the undefined problems), or `CanActivate` can mediate navigation to a route (the usecase the Angular tutorial uses is for authentication). Or maybe you should rethink how your data is accessed so that its not tied directly to your app.component; a service sounds needed here.

Comment: No, i am not relying on guards. The problem is that the content of "path1"s component depends on settings made in root's component. Therefore, navigating to path1 without previously making the settings, does not sensibly make sense.

Comment: Architecting the app like that might make sense to you, but would your users understand _why_ they ended up back on the root if they refresh? Probably not bc that breaks established expectations on how the web works. You could potentially pass the needed settings as queryparams, grab those in `path1`'s resolver, and then load the needed data. That way onRefresh the app has what it needs to display correctly and the user doesn't experience the confusion of being forcibly redirected. Anyway I'll stop badgering you about architecture since comments aren't for extended discussion. Good luck!